# How do you print variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I'm only in secondary school so I'm not even competent at coding, but my school website is down and I cant find some answers to questions in python coding. There's probably a really simple answer, but I cant remember how to print a variable. the variable I simply a string of numbers I am sorting and I cant fid out how to print the variable. can anyone show me what to write to print the variable?

Comment: `print(my_variable)`

Comment: The rest of the Internet is not down, is it? Google must be still up and running...

Comment: Well, I know why are here.. you searched online..and all you get is python 2 codes?

Comment: @DyZ It never fails to amaze me. It takes longer to make an SO account, write a post like this, and wait for answers than it does to literally put the name of the post into Google.

Comment: I apologise, but as I only understand very basic coding most of the answers online are difficult to understand and I hoped I might get a clearer answer from here.

Comment: @dfundako the OP says they are a secondary school pupil. There are lessons to be learned, but at that age they may not know that you can Google programming questions

Comment: @roganjosh I'm not buying it. Google has answers to anything and everything. Copy/Paste this post title into Google and there are examples that are absolutely beginner level and basic.

Comment: @roganjosh Secondary school (in the UK) is 11-16, I assume an 11 year old can use Google?

Comment: I know people in their 20's that use a calculator to fill in cells in an Excel sheet. Anyways, I closed it along with others, but I don't wanna seem too harsh to kids trying to learn

Comment: you can use the logging module and the pprint library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 2 : `print variable_to_print`. If you are on Python 3 : `print(variable_to_print)`.